# VBA code to select cell based on COUNTA formula

Tags: excel, vba, count

i would like to select a cell in column U (see yellow highlight) based on how many names are counted in column X + add 1 to get the right row.
To illustrate, the highlighted yellow cell.
Thank you.

![]: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pua8G.png)

Comment: I do not understand your question... Which 'many names' should be counted in that column? You show us (in the picture) highlighted **cells**, not a cell. So, can you better describe **based on what** to select the cells in discussion? Besides that, do you have a piece of code done on your own, or collected from internet? Maybe we better understand what is to be done looking to the code... Does the empty cell in column W:W play a part in the selection logic?

Comment: Hello, i highlighted 1 yellow cell which i want to select now after i got data from server highlighted blue. Basically i want to counta the cells in X:X and add 1 to get the yellow cell in column U:U .. I want a vba code to every time select the first blank cell in U:U (but there are blanks before in U:U thats why i want to counta X:X) Hope i clarified

Comment: Do you mean, the last cell on column U:U?

Comment: Yes, i want to select the cell which i made yellow. But the cell above can be blank in some case ... so i think to get the right row nr names in X:X must be counted

Comment: No need of counting. Please, see my answer...

Comment: Im sorry, what i mean the cell isnt yellow or anything, normal cell... the cell selected changes every time, because i get data from my server, then i want to select the bottom cell, get new data, select bottom cell again. Hope i clarified

Comment: This was obvious... My code answer colors its interior in red. Only for you, to be sure that the code found the cell what you need. You can comment the coloring line, of course... Didn't you test my code answer?

Comment: https://www.upload.ee/image/11908792/222.PNG i got data from server, now i need to select cell U125 ... your code didnt work, interior color row returns error 1004

Comment: Did you test my code?

Comment: If i remove interior color row, it returns to cell W1491, last row where by side i have formulas

Comment: I need rows count X:X + 1 and range U:U

Comment: This only means that you have a filled cell at W1490... Isn't it true? Can you better explain what logic to be applied in order to highlight that specific cell?

Comment: Do you have gaps (empty cells) in row X:X? Are there other filled cells after what we can see in the picture? If not, try the adapted code. It will highlight last rows of W and U (interior blue) based on the last cell in X:X.

Comment: New code doesnt work, if i remove the colour stuff, it selects row 1491, the cells are empty but in other columns i have formulas so thats the end of my sheet. It really directs to the last empty cell. Only in X:X columns are no blanks in data. The point is that i get data from server, then i want to select the bottom cell not to overwrite the old data, when i get new data with a vba call! The goal is to save a database- check the upload.ee image i need to get cell U125

Comment: So, is 124 your last filled row (in X:X column)? And nothing in this column after row 124. If yes, you did not refresh the page (this one) and you use an old code variant. Does your code has the next line: `lastEmptyRow = sh.Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row`?

Comment: Takes me to row 1491 , correct in X:X 124 is the last filled row , also in your code the color and W:W range is not needed, i only need to count X:X and with that can get the correct row in U:U

Comment: I am afraid it is not. In fact, I am sure that you have something on X1490. Please, click on X125 cell. Then put the cursor on the bottom part of the cell and execute double click. Does it bring you on X1490 cell? If ies, look in the formula bar, maybe there is/are empty space/s in there... Are there anu formulas after X124?

Comment: Hey, it works on a new sheet! hmm i have to check over , but you wrote the right code, thanks a lot!! All the best !

Comment: Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the left answer code side to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code worked. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testLastCell()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastEmptyRow As Long, rngEmptyW As Range, rngEmptyU As Range
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastEmptyRow = sh.Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
 Set rngEmptyW = sh.Range("W" & lastEmptyRow)
    rngEmptyW.Interior.Color = RGB(225, 0, 0)
    rngEmptyW.Select
    
 Set rngEmptyU = sh.Range("U" & lastEmptyRow)
     rngEmptyU.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 225)
End Sub
```

The above code will color the interior of the last empty cell in red and select it...